# How to resolve recursive promise?

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I have code like below:

```js
function addNumberToFilename(filename) {
    var newFilename = "";
    var textInsideParentheses = filename.match(/\(([^)]+)\)/);
    if (textInsideParentheses !== null && textInsideParentheses[1] !== undefined) {
        // have parentheses
        var numInParentheses = parseInt(textInsideParentheses[1]);
        var nextNumInParentheses = numInParentheses + 1;
        newFilename = filename.replace(/\(.*?\)/, String('(' + nextNumInParentheses + ')'))
    } else {
        // have not parentheses
        var reForExtensionExtract = /(?:\.([^.]+))?$/;
        var extension = reForExtensionExtract.exec(filename)[1];
        var fileNameWithoutExtenstion = filename.replace(/\..+$/, '');
        newFilename = fileNameWithoutExtenstion + '(1)' + '.' + extension;
    }

    checkIfFileExist(newFilename);
}


function checkIfFileExist(filename, path) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var fileWithThatFilenameFound = false;
        local.files.listFolder({
            "path": "default:\\",
            "filter": ["Img"]
        }, {
            success: function (result) {
                result.map(function (elem) {
                    if (elem.itemName === filename) { // file with that filename exists
                        // so add parentheses or increase them
                        fileWithThatFilenameFound = true;
                        addNumberToFilename(filename);
                    }
                });

                if (!fileWithThatFilenameFound) {
                    // end of the recursion chain! let's resolve finally
                    resolve(filename);
                }
            }
        });
    });
}


...


checkIfFileExist(snapshot.filename + '.jpg').then(function(newFileName) {
    local.images.save({
        fileName: newFileName
    })
});
```

But I have problem with that.

If there is no recursion at all (filename not exist, so resolve is execute within first promise) everything works. But if filename exist (and chain is checkIfFileExist -> addNumberToFilename -> checkIfFileExist -> resolve() ) resolve() does not work.

Why? How can I resolve recursive promise?

Comment: I have changed `checkIfFileExist(newFilename);` to `return checkIfFileExist(newFilename);` in `addNumberToFilename` function, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have to return your promises:

```
function addNumberToFilename(filename) {

  //...
  return checkIfFileExist(newFilename);
}
```

and

```
checkIfFileExist(snapshot.filename + '.jpg')
  .then( ( fileName ) => local.images.save({ fileName }) )
```

**edited after the comment:**

```
function checkIfFileExist( filename ) {
    //simplyfied a bit
    return new Promise( function ( resolve, reject ) {
        resolve false;
    } )
}

function saveFile( newFileName ) {

    return local.images.save( {
        fileName: newFileName
    } )
    // the second argument wasn't useful at all
}

function save() {

    return checkIfFileExist( snapshot.filename + '.jpg' )
        .then( saveFile )
        .catch( err => console.error( err ) )
}
```

I see many problems scattered around:

- `local.images.save` is a function?
- it returns a promise?
- the promise is fulfilling?

Comment: It doesn't work. My code on main checkIfFileExist call is: https://jsfiddle.net/pv92v9h0/